# Prints one call after

Tags: c, debugging, printf

I am trying to call a function, which appeared not to be working. So i added a few printf() and this is the result.

```
if (rc > 0) {
            bzero(buffer,256);
            n = read(sockfd,buffer,255);
            if (n < 0) 
                 error("ERROR reading from socket");
            printf("ListenPort() got this: %s",buffer);
            useEvent("maybe this works"); //ONLY a print statement.
            printf("Test");
        }
```

On the first call of this function i only get:

```
ListenPort() got this: A
```

On the second call I get:

```
useEvent() Test ListenPort() got this: A
```

Two print staments from the PREVIOUS call and 1 from the new. This means that somehow useEvent() is not run until the second called is made or something of that sort.

I hope you don't need more code, but let me know and I will post it.

Comment: `printf` may buffer data until it encounters a newline.  You could try flushing `stdout` or adding a newline `\n` at the end of your print messages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default stdout is line-buffered. Add `fflush(stdout);` at the end of the `if` block.